# Django отображение шаблона в зависимости от роли пользователя

Tags: python, django

Разрабатываю проект на Django, есть необходимость изменять вид главной страницы в зависимости от роли вошедшего пользователя. Есть две роли: администраторы и обычные пользователи. Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы после авторизации на сайте пользователю выводился html шаблон в зависимости от его роли.
Пока что реализация выглядит так:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
if request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists():
    template = 'index_admin.html'
elif request.user.groups.filter(name='users').exists():
    template = 'index_user.html'
return render(request, template)
```

Однако уверен, что есть более правильная и надежная реализация данного функционала. Возможно ли как-то доработать эту проверку?

Answer (score 1):

я вижу еще два варианта:

1. Передавать значение функции request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists() в шаблон в качестве аргумента:

   is_admin = request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists()
   context = {'is_admin': is_admin}
   return render(request, 'index_user.html', context)

в шаблоне можно уже более гибко управлять содержанием:

```
{% if is_admin %}
 что-то выводим для админа
{% else %}
 вывод для пользователя
{% endif %}
```

2. Кастомизировать модель пользователя джанги и создать метод проверки на админа:

   class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   some_extra_data = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   def is_admin(self):
   if self.groups.name == 'Admin':
   return True
   else:
   return False

Затем в шаблоне можно выполнить проверку на админа:

```
{% if request.user.is_admin %}
  что-то выводим для админа
{% else %}
 вывод для пользователя
{% endif %}
```